# Update post meta with wp cron

Tags: functions, loop, advanced-custom-fields, wp-cron

I am trying to create a function (which I will trigger through the WP Cron) but no values are passed and the database values remain *NULL*. Could anyone point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong?

I am trying to compare multiple dates against todays date, keep the future ones, store in an array, and get the first available date in the future -> store this in a new post_meta field. Update the value daily vi WP cron and use this field to sort the posts.

This is my current code with comments:

```
/*
* ACF Field Structure:
*
* - jurisdiction_release_date (Repeater)
*   - jurisdiction_date_selection (Group)
*      - alt_release_date (Date Picker)
*      - alt_jurisdiction (Taxonomy)
*      - alt_release_date_option (Select)
*/

function update_game_release_date() {    

    $game_args = array( 
        'post_type'=>'games',
        'posts_per_page'=>'-1',
        'post_status '=> 'publish',    
        'fields' => 'ids'
    );

    // The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $game_args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        // execute for each post
        $current_date = date('Ymd');
        $alt_release_dates = array();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        if( have_rows('jurisdiction_release_date') ):
        while( have_rows('jurisdiction_release_date') ) : the_row();
        //load group
        if( have_rows('jurisdiction_date_selection') ):
            while( have_rows('jurisdiction_date_selection') ): the_row(); 
            // load field values
            $alt_release_date = get_sub_field('alt_release_date');
            // only list if jurisdiction date is larger than today's date (in the future)
            if ($alt_release_date > $current_date) {
            // Add all future dates to the array
            array_push( $alt_release_dates, $alt_release_date );
        }
            endwhile;
        endif;
        endwhile;
        // only future release dates are now stored in an array. Just select the next (smallest) by using min()
        //create new variable from array in template above
        $release_date = min($alt_release_dates);
        else:
        // If not dates added, get date value from ACF field 'release_date'
        $release_date = get_field('release_date');
        endif;
        // Update the post meta field '_release_date_hidden' with the new value stored in variable $release_date
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_release_date_hidden', $release_date );

    }
    
} }

// The wordpress Cron
add_action( 'update_cron', 'update_game_release_date' );

if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'update_cron' ) ) {  
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'update_cron' );  
}
```

Comment: Have you tested if your CRON is running? Are you getting any errors?  You need to create a date time from your ACF field to compare.  I'm not seeing that.

Comment: Hi @rudtek yes the cron is running, when adding values manually to the data base, after the cron all values are back to NULL, so the cron is running but its just not passing the correct data. I'm getting the subfield $alt_release_date = get_sub_field('alt_release_date'); and comparing it with $current_date = date('Ymd');

Comment: You're going to love this...  the other day, when I tried to ONLY get `ids` I had a real struggle... ...ends up that using `get_posts()` instead of `WP_Query()` was the solution.  Try just switching from `WP_Query` to `get_posts` and see if that makes a difference.  (Will be honest that it doesn't seem right, but that did solve the problem for me.)